# Avoid damaged data for SELECT and UPDATE query and long-running task in between

Tags: mysql, transactions, transaction-isolation

I have two applications `exporter` and `payment_handler`

- `exporter` does a `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status="PAID"`, processes the rows (about 5 minutes) and finally does an `UPDATE orders SET status="EXPORTED" WHERE status="PAID"`
- `payment_handler` executes `UPDATE orders SET status="PAID" WHERE status="UNPAID"`

Without transaction isolation, this would lead to the wrong data being updated when `payment_handler` runs while `exporter` processes the rows: The `UPDATE` statement of the exporter will mark orders as exported that the `SELECT` statement did not select before.

If I wrap exporter in a transaction and do the `SELECT` with a `FOR UPDATE` qualifier, `payment handler` will be blocked until `exporter` is finished, because MySQL does not allow new inserts of `status="PAID"`. But the payment handler must not be blocked for such a long time.

My current workaround is to avoid the transaction and create my own "snapshot" into the data: `exporter` creates a temporary table `export_ids` and does an insert like this: `INSERT INTO export_ids SELECT id FROM order WHERE status="PAID"`. All subsequent SELECT and UPDATE operations for the `order` table in `exporter` will join/subselect the `export_id` table. Performance- and storage-wise this works fine, since there will be only about 100k entries in `export_ids` for one export.

But I'm wondering if I'm using MySQLs transaction levels wrong and if there is any better way to achieve the behavior?

Comment: Maybe you should share some code so we have a better understanding/idea what you are doing as code tells more then "1000" words..

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - But where do you see a possible "race condition"? The *exporter* selects only rows with `status="PAID"`. The *payment_handler* doesn't touch any of those rows. Or do you really run `UPDATE orders SET status="EXPORTED"` without a WHERE condition?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I've updated the question to be more precise. The *payment_handler* updates the status to the exact value that the *exporter* does the SELECT and UPDATE on.

Comment: In my eyes you're doing this the right way. I'm not aware of another way to avoid blocking. Of course I assume you have done everything you can to speed up the exporter process and it's still to slow.

Comment: You can see code examples at https://github.com/gbirke/transaction-test

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do this:

```
UPDATE orders SET status="EXPORTED" WHERE status="PAID"
```

You know exactly, which rows you have selected, so you should be able to update the same rows by using their primary keys. So your query should be

```
UPDATE orders SET status="EXPORTED" WHERE id IN (<list of previously selected ids>)
```

This is actually equivalent to what you do with the temporary table. And that is all you need in this particular case. Because it's not about transactions and locking, but just about identifying the correct rows.

Note: I don't say you don't need locks. You probably do. But not for these two tasks.

Comment: He said he processes around 100k rows, so the temporary table actually is most likely the better option. 100.000*4 Byte (integer) is around 0,4MB. You can easily use a memory engine table.

Comment: @fancyPants The IDs are in the application either way - so why not use them? Don't forget - We are talking about a script running for 5 minutes. So 0.1 seconds more or less will not hurt much. However - I don't even really care which method to use. The point is to identify the rows by primary key. BTW: I wouldn't feel comfortable using temp tables in write queries. Depending on server settings (log format), there can be issues in some crash scenarios.